# How to make box plots within the same column to represent the soil column

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, cowplot

I am trying to demonstrate the soil type (soil column) at different depths in the ground using box plots. However, as the sampling interval is not consistent, there are also gaps in between the samples.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is it possible to put the box plots within the same column? i.e. all box plots in 1 straight column
2. Is it possible to remove the x-axis labels and ticks when using `ggdraw`? I tried to remove it when using plot, but appears again when I use `ggdraw`.

My code looks like this:

```
 SampleID <- c("Rep-1", "Rep-2", "Rep-3", "Rep-4")
 From <- c(0,2,4,9)
 To <- c(1,4,8,10)
 Mid <- (From+To)/2
 ImaginaryVal <- c(1,1,1,1)
 Soiltype <- c("organic", "silt","clay", "sand")
 df <- data.frame(SampleID, From, To, Mid, ImaginaryVal, Soiltype)

 plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=ImaginaryVal, ymin=From, lower=From,fill=Soiltype,
            middle=`Mid`, upper=To, ymax=To)) +
          geom_boxplot(colour= "black", stat="identity") +                              scale_y_reverse(breaks = seq(0,10,0.5)) + xlab('Soiltype') +                  ylab('Depth (m)') + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),                    axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) 

 ggdraw(switch_axis_position(plot + theme_bw(8), axis = 'x'))
```

[image]

In the image I have pointed out what I want, using the red arrows and lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `position = position_dodge()` like so:

```
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=ImaginaryVal, ymin=From, lower=From,fill=Soiltype, middle=Mid, upper=To, ymax=To)) +
  geom_boxplot(colour= "black", stat="identity", position = position_dodge(width=0)) + 
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = seq(0,10,0.5)) + 
  xlab('Soiltype') + 
  ylab('Depth (m)') + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

*edit*: I don't think you need cowplot at all, if this is what you want your plot to look like:

[image]

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=ImaginaryVal, ymin=From, lower=From,fill=Soiltype, middle=Mid, upper=To, ymax=To)) +
  geom_boxplot(colour= "black", stat="identity", position = position_dodge(width=0)) + 
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = seq(0,10,0.5)) + 
  xlab('Soiltype') + 
  ylab('Depth (m)') + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  xlab("") +
  ggtitle("Soiltype")
```

Comment: O my goodness. I have no words to describe how happy and satisfied I am with your answer. This totally solved my problem. Thank You very very much @beetroot.

Comment: Also, is there a way that we can remove the "mid" lines within each box ?

Comment: Glad to help, but maybe you'd be better off using `geom_rect` instead of `geom_boxplot`? try `ggplot(df, aes(xmin=1, xmax=3, ymin=From, fill=Soiltype,  ymax=To)) +
  geom_rect(colour= "black")` ...

Comment: Yes, I tried it with the geom_rect, and this seems to be the best. Thank You once again

Comment: I did accept your answer :-), but it says I have to have 15 reputations to make my vote public. I think it will be visible once I have 15 reputations. Or, please correct me if I am wrong here. Thanks